# To edit and delete the tabular rows in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have employees array that consist of employeeid, name and location. I need to edit, delete, update,add and save them in a tabular column.I was successful in viewing the table, however, as i searched on web, i got two similar links that show how to edit,cancel and save the employees. The links are :
     https://jsfiddle.net/UWLFJ/1970/  and 
     http://blog.shubhamsaxena.com/creating-simple-inline-editing-with-angularjs/

I fail to accomplish the task. I am getting error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined .(app.js:58). Please help me accomplish it.

**index.html** -

```
 <html ng-app="Swabhav.Employee">
  <head>
    <title>Employee</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

     <script src="app.js"></script>
     <section ng-view></section>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**app.js**

```
   angular.module("Swabhav.Employee",['ngRoute'])
      .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

       $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
         controller:"HomeController",
         templateUrl:"home.html"

     })

  }])


     angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")

    .factory("EmployeeService",["$log",function($log){

     var employees=[{"empId":1,"name":"John","location":"Mumbai"},
                    {"empId":2,"name":"Nikita","location":"Mumbai"},
                     {"empId":3,"name":"Saurab","location":"Pune"},
                    {"empId":4,"name":"Ankita","location":"Bangalore"},
                    {"empId":5,"name":"Harsh","location":"Chennai"},
                    {"empId":6, "name":"Geeta","location":"Vellore"}];

       var obj={};

      obj.displayAll=function(){

                    return employees;
               }       

    return obj;

    }])

   angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
       .controller("HomeController",
  ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log",function($scope,EmployeeService,$log){

   $log.log (EmployeeService.displayAll());   

   $scope.data=EmployeeService.displayAll();

   $scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
    if (employee.id == $scope.selected.id){
     return 'edit';
    }
    else 
    return 'display';
   };

     $scope.editEmployee=function(employee){
       $scope.selected=angular.copy(employee);
    }



   $scope.saveEmployee = function (index) {
    console.log("Saving employee");
    $scope.data[index] = angular.copy($scope.selected);
    $scope.reset();
   };

  $scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.selected = {};
  };
  }])
```

**home.html**

```
   <article>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th> Edit </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in data" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">


            <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
            <td>{{employee.empId}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.location}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-
    click="editEmployee(employee)">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-
    click="deleteEmployee(employee)">Delete</button></td>
            </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.empId"></td>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.name" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.location" /></td>
         <td>
        <button ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
         </td>
     </script>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table> 

  </article>
```

Comment: can you post your response JSON ?

Comment: how to get that?

Comment: just console your JSON.stringify($scope.data). and paste that

Comment: employees is your data ?

Comment: [{"empId":1,"name":"John","location":"Mumbai"},{"empId":2,"name":"Nikita","location":"Mumbai"},{"empId":3,"name":"Saurab","location":"Pune"},{"empId":4,"name":"Ankita","location":"Bangalore"},{"empId":5,"name":"Harsh","location":"Chennai"},{"empId":6,"name":"Geeta","location":"Vellore"}]

Comment: @sangram ...employees is my data

Comment: check the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
    if (employee.empId== $scope.selected.id){
     return 'edit';
    }
    else 
    return 'display';
};
```

change to `employee.empId`

You need to modify the row like below

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
```

For edit and delete you need to use below.

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEmployee(employee, $index)">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee,$index)">Delete</button></td>
```

**APP.JS**

```
$scope.editEmployee = function(employee, index) {
            console.log(employee);
            $scope.selected = angular.copy(employee);
        }

        $scope.deleteEmployee = function(employee, index) {
            console.log(index);
            $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
        }
```

Check https://plnkr.co/edit/A0I3ZdSBIS7jGSyUNhC8?p=preview

Comment: @java_jazz please check my plunker. i have fixed it. your problem was at `ng-include="getTemplate(employee)"` and i removed it to `<tr ng-repeat="employee in data">` https://plnkr.co/edit/A0I3ZdSBIS7jGSyUNhC8?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

**home.html**

```
<article>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th> Edit </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table> 

</article>
```

**display.html**

```
<td>{{employee.empId}}</td>
<td>{{employee.name}}</td>
<td>{{employee.location}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng- 
click="editEmployee(employee)">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng- 
click="deleteEmployee($index)">Delete</button></td>
```

**edit.html**

```
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.empId"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.location" /></td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="saveEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
    </td>
```

**app.js**

```
    angular.module("Swabhav.Employee",['ngRoute'])
      .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

       $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
         controller:"HomeController",
         templateUrl:"home.html"

     })

  }])


     angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")

    .factory("EmployeeService",["$log",function($log){

     var employees=[{"empId":1,"name":"John","location":"Mumbai"},
                    {"empId":2,"name":"Nikita","location":"Mumbai"},
                     {"empId":3,"name":"Saurab","location":"Pune"},
                    {"empId":4,"name":"Ankita","location":"Bangalore"},
                    {"empId":5,"name":"Harsh","location":"Chennai"},
                    {"empId":6, "name":"Geeta","location":"Vellore"}];

       var obj={};

      obj.displayAll=function(){

                    return employees;
               }       

    return obj;

    }])

   angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
       .controller("HomeController",
  ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log",function($scope,EmployeeService,$log){

   $log.log (EmployeeService.displayAll());   

   $scope.data=EmployeeService.displayAll();

   $scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
    if ($scope.selected  != undefined) {
        if (employee.empId == $scope.selected.empId){ return 'edit.html'; }
    }
      return 'display.html';

   };

     $scope.editEmployee=function(employee){
      console.log(employee);
       $scope.selected=angular.copy(employee);
    }

      $scope.deleteEmployee=function($index){
        console.log($index);
        $scope.data.splice($index , 1);
      }



   $scope.saveEmployee = function (index) {
    console.log("Saving employee");
    $scope.data[index] = $scope.selected;
    $scope.reset();
   };

  $scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.selected = {};
  };
  }])
```

Comment: key word is "of undefined", meaning the object itself is undefined, not the properties of that object

Comment: It works now, However your should improve your app structure. I think you made it kind of complex for such easy Scenario.

Comment: Try now i wrote the delete function for you, You didn't Wrote any delete function. so i left it like it was.